# APCUPSD script can't close program

Tags: linux, shell-script, permissions

I want to use APCUPSD to stop a program (called `ns_image_server`) which runs in a terminal window when it detects that power has been lost, to give that program time to close before the computer shuts down. When power is lost, APCUPSD calls a shell script called `onbattery` which has the command `ns_image_server stop`. However, nothing happens when I unplug the UPS. I know the script is getting called because it will echo, and I can run other scripts which stop `ns_image_server`, but this one doesn't seem to work.

I assume it's some kind of permissions problem, but wouldn't APCUPSD (and the scripts it calls) be running as root anyway? (still a bit of a novice, so correct me if I'm wrong)

The result of `ls -la onbattery*`:

```
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root 449 Jun 16 14:22 onbattery
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 438 Jun 15 18:08 onbattery~
```

The script `onbattery` is just:

```
#!/bin/sh
ns_image_server stop
exit 0
```

Comment: Can you post the script? and the output of `ls -la onbattery*` of the dir with the script?

Comment: Done. Sorry if you got spammed with notifications of me trying and failing to put that information into a comment instead of in the post.

Comment: Can you add a line `exec >/tmp/output 2>&1` as the 2nd line of `onbattery` and show us what it outputs?

Comment: That seems to have created an empty file.

Comment: Is `ns_image_server` a shell script?

Comment: No it is not, but it runs in a terminal window.